# boost::asio::socket keep alive set_option exception

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I create a socket like so :

```
client<THeader>::client(boost::asio::io_service* io_service, std::string const & host, int port)
    :_host(host), 
    _port(port), 
    _socket(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(*io_service)), 
    _io_service(io_service)
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
    _socket.set_option(option, ec);
    bool is_set = option.value();
}
```

`is_set` is `true`. But `ec` has a non-zero value. How am I to understand this? I can use the socket afterwards though. It seems it's working ok.

ec.what() = `set_option: The file handle supplied is not valid`

Comment: And what error is set in `ec`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : error value is 10009

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : `set_option: The file handle supplied is not valid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`open`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/open.html) the socket before you can use it. Before you call [`open`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/open.html) the actual underlying socket descriptor is not created.

Alternatively use a [constructor that both create the object and opens the socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload2.html).